# Global variable is not defined when using tkinter and Combobox (GUI)

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, global-variables

The following codes let me choose three things in `Combobox` and then based on what I chose, the function will do some basic calculation.

```
import openpyxl
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from openpyxl import Workbook  # or "from openpyxl import Workbook": create workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook # open/excess excel file or spreadsheet existed

def selected1(event):
    global var1 
    if mycombobox.get() == 'clam shell':
        var1 = 1
        return var1
    if mycombobox.get() == '360\u00b0':
        var1 = 2
        return var1

def selected2(event):
    global var2
    if mycombobox1.get() == 'hinge':
        var2 = 3
        return var2
    if mycombobox1.get() == 'top':
        var2 = 4
        return var2

def selected3(event):
    global var3 
    if mycombobox2.get() == 'hinge':
        var3 = 5
        return var3
    if mycombobox2.get() == 'top':
        var3 = 6
        return var3
    
def sol_analysis(selected1,selected2,selected3):
    var4 = var1 + var2 + var3
    return var4

# ========================= main ==============================

root = Tk()
root.title('Industry Solution')
root.geometry("500x800")

#  === Type ===

label_a = Label(root, text="1. type of computer")
label_a.pack(side = TOP, pady=1) 
type_com = ['Type', 'clam shell', '360\u00b0']
mycombobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values = type_com)
mycombobox.current(0)
mycombobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',selected1)
mycombobox.pack(side = TOP, pady=1) 

#  === WLAN1 position ===

label_b = Label(root, text="2. WLAN1 antenna position")
label_b.pack(side = TOP, pady=1) 
WLAN1_ant = ['WLAN1 ant. position', 'hinge', 'top']
mycombobox1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values = WLAN1_ant)
mycombobox1.current(0)
mycombobox1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',selected2)
mycombobox1.pack(side = TOP, pady=1) 

#  === WLAN2 position ===

label_c = Label(root, text="3. WLAN2 antenna position")
label_c.pack(side = TOP, pady=1) 
WLAN2_ant = ['WLAN2 ant. position', 'hinge', 'top']
mycombobox2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values = WLAN2_ant)
mycombobox2.current(0)
mycombobox2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',selected3)
mycombobox2.pack(side = TOP, pady=1) 

# === Result ===

sol_analysis(selected1,selected2,selected3)


root.mainloop()
```

In my code, I want to select three things before doing the calculation. However, when I ran the codes, the error popped out before choosing anything.

The error I got is:

```
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined
```

I defined all three variables by `global vari`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`global var1` doesn't "declare" the variable; it does something more like "when you reference the variable named `var1`, look in the global namespace".  There is no such variable, hence the error.

```py
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def get_var1():
...     global var1
...     return var1
... 
>>> get_var1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_var1
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined
>>> var1 = 10
>>> get_var1()
10
```

Try initializing var1, etc., before you call `sol_analysis`, to say 0, and you won't get the name error.

I don't think this code will do what you want: you need to trigger `sol_analysis` from something, maybe a button in your GUI.